# Brains in combat chassis

Tags: novel, robots, story-identification

I cannot for the life of me remember the name of this book. One main part was the earth had been invaded and people were volunteering for their brains to be wired into large robots/ combat chassis and there were different versions of chassis? I know it's vague but it's all I can remember!!

Sorry! The book I read was in the late 80's in English. Am sure it was set in the uk, the main character had lost a loved one and went for the programme to become one of these things, can't remember anything else

Comment: Hi there! Any more information you can add would be really helpful- when did you read this book?  Was it new or old at the time?  Did you read it in English?  In the US?  What did the cover look like?  Little details like that might spark someone's memory.

Comment: Have added what little else I know! Sadly not much .

Answer (score 5):

Soldiers by John Dalmas

An alien migration fleet of 14,000 starships searches for a new home, its homeworld lost forever. When they find planets that can support them, they eradicate the human natives. But Earth's Commonwealth of Worlds isn't about to give up so easily, even if it has to create and train something it's not had for centuries: "soldiers".

[Link to book cover](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/d/john-dalmas/soldiers.htm)

From what I remember of the book, most of the soldiers have normal combat chasis armour, but some (cant remember if its cos they are terminal, old or badly injured) have their brains implanted in robotic soldier bodies.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't completely fit, but there's [Keith Laumer's "A Plague of Demons."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer#Standalone_books)

Earth hasn't been invaded, but...

> ...aliens have infiltrated earth and are kidnapping people in order to get their brains, which are taken to a distant planet and installed into giant fighting machines (I haven't read it for a while, I think they're more like Bolo tanks than robots).

It's a good read: lots of action, much like Worlds of the Imperium and A Trace of Memory.

[image: plague cover]

Answer (score 4):

Cyborg Commando was an RPG game that featured an invaded earth and humans putting their brains into robot bodies. It had a series of books based on the property. As listed on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_Commando , they are:

1.Planet in Peril by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. Published in November 1987 by Ace/New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-66883-6.
 2.Chase into Space by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. Published in January 1988 by New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-10294-8.
 3.The Ultimate Prize by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. Published in March 1988 by New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-84325-5.

The enemy was primarily giant bugs in that story line.

The story is set in the US, and does feature a lost love that is eventually reunited.

Comment: I have the first book in that series. It does sound like the OP's request.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly "Legion of the Damned," by William C. Dietz?  The story has some elements of your description.

[Legion at amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441480403)