# Looking for a book about alien insects invading earth

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book back in the late 80s or early 90s about earth being invaded by aliens that looked a lot like insects.  I thought it was written by Gary Gygax but I can't figure out what they were called.  I think there were 3 books in the series.  The protagonist was a young man.   Sorry I can't remember any more than that.

Answer (score 6):

Gygax and alien bugs can only be  [Cyborg Commando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_Commando). Though the link leads to the game Wikipedia page, there were three novels written to go with the release. Those of us raised on Gygax's legendary Dungeons and Dragons do not like to talk about "Cyborg Commando." The novels and the game are deeply forgettable.

Stealing from the Wikipedia link, the novels are:

- **Planet in Peril** by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. 

  Published in November 1987 by Ace/New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-66883-6.
- **Chase into Space** by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. 
  Published in January 1988 by New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-10294-8.
- **The Ultimate Prize** by Kim Mohan and Pamela O'Neill. 
  Published in March 1988 by New Infinities, Inc. ISBN 0-441-84325-5.

Comment: I think that's it. Thank you for the super fast response. Take care, -R

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/brains-in-combat-chassis/35137#35137, but the answer is unconfirmed there.